# Navigation within pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, navigation, gallery

Some friends of mine am starting an art blog and am aiming to use WordPress for usability reasons as their PHP/HTML/CSS experience is minimal. However, we are running into a roadblock in that we are finding it difficult to accomplish multi-level navigation within Wordpress: that is; for each WordPress 'page', there must be several 'sub-pages'. For example, each artist page (eg Zac) must have several separate sub-pages: an "About", a "Gallery" (which will be accomplished with a separate WordPress plugin) and a blog sorted by a specific category. An additional road block is presented in the form that each sub-page navigation must be separate from the main navigation: ie, not a drop-down menu, but rather a separate menu located elsewhere on the page.

I've looked around at some WordPress multi-level navigation plugins but haven't found any that adequately meet these needs. Has anyone had the same problem, and if so, how did you work around it? Is there a suitable plugin or will I need to create a separate Page template and then hand-code About/Gallery sections in separate PHP files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use categories to do that. What I suggest you to do is to create a category for each person and then create sub-categories, sub-pages or posts under each one.

You can then create template that will target different type of pages, you can also target some keywords.